# how to list the images paths in the directory in python?

Tags: python

I created one folder called dataset, then in this folder i created subfolder called subfold1, subfold2

`names=[]`

```
for users in os.listdir("dataset"):
    names.append(users)

print(names)
```

Output:
`['subfold1','subfold2']`

In the subfold1 , i have 5 images and subfold2 also i have 5 images

Then, i want to list the images paths which i have inside the subfold1 and subfol2?

```
path= []
for name in names:
    for image in os.listdir("dataset/{}".format(name)):
        path_string = os.path.join("dataset/{}".format(name), image)
        path.append(path_string)

print(path)
```

My output is

```
['dataset/subfold1\\1_1.jpg', 'dataset/subfold1\\1_2.jpg', 'dataset/subfold1\\1_3.jpg', 'dataset/subfold1\\1_4.jpg', 'dataset/subfold1\\1_5.jpg', 'dataset/subfold2\\2_1.jpg', 'dataset/subfold3\\2_2.jpg', 'dataset/subfold2\\2_3.jpg', 'dataset/subfold2\\2_4.jpg', 'dataset/subfold2\\2_5.jpg']
```

I want the correct paths

Answer (score 1):

quick solution;

use `os.path.normpath` for normalizing a path (modifying every separator to `os.path.sep` AND adapting the path to the `operating system`)

```
paths = [
    'dataset/subfold1\\1_1.jpg', 
    'dataset/subfold1\\1_2.jpg', 
    'dataset/subfold1\\1_3.jpg', 
    'dataset/subfold1\\1_4.jpg', 
    'dataset/subfold1\\1_5.jpg', 
    'dataset/subfold2\\2_1.jpg', 
    'dataset/subfold3\\2_2.jpg', 
    'dataset/subfold2\\2_3.jpg', 
    'dataset/subfold2\\2_4.jpg', 
    'dataset/subfold2\\2_5.jpg'
]
import os
paths = list(map(os.path.normpath, paths))

>>> paths
```

out

```
['dataset\\subfold1\\1_1.jpg',
 'dataset\\subfold1\\1_2.jpg',
 'dataset\\subfold1\\1_3.jpg',
 'dataset\\subfold1\\1_4.jpg',
 'dataset\\subfold1\\1_5.jpg',
 'dataset\\subfold2\\2_1.jpg',
 'dataset\\subfold3\\2_2.jpg',
 'dataset\\subfold2\\2_3.jpg',
 'dataset\\subfold2\\2_4.jpg',
 'dataset\\subfold2\\2_5.jpg']
```

extra info:

- you cant get rid of this `\\` from this `'dataset/subfold1\\1_1.jpg'` because that is the `string __repr__` of the element, and when you do `__repr__` you see `double backslash` because its escaped. if you will actually print the value on the screen you will see just one `\`

quick demo:

```
print('dataset\\subfold1\\1_1.jpg')
```

out

```
dataset\subfold1\1_1.jpg
```

- if you really want to `join` the paths with `/` then make your `own join function 4 paths` (also i dont recommend this, i made that in the past and i realised that it was worthless, because os.path is handling everything for you)

`but` if you are on windows and you `really` want to have `linux path separator` you can try this:

```
paths = [
    'dataset/subfold1\\1_1.jpg', 
    'dataset/subfold1\\1_2.jpg', 
    'dataset/subfold1\\1_3.jpg', 
    'dataset/subfold1\\1_4.jpg', 
    'dataset/subfold1\\1_5.jpg', 
    'dataset/subfold2\\2_1.jpg', 
    'dataset/subfold3\\2_2.jpg', 
    'dataset/subfold2\\2_3.jpg', 
    'dataset/subfold2\\2_4.jpg', 
    'dataset/subfold2\\2_5.jpg'
]
paths = [path.replace("\\", "/") for path in paths]
>>> paths
```

out

```
['dataset/subfold1/1_1.jpg',
 'dataset/subfold1/1_2.jpg',
 'dataset/subfold1/1_3.jpg',
 'dataset/subfold1/1_4.jpg',
 'dataset/subfold1/1_5.jpg',
 'dataset/subfold2/2_1.jpg',
 'dataset/subfold3/2_2.jpg',
 'dataset/subfold2/2_3.jpg',
 'dataset/subfold2/2_4.jpg',
 'dataset/subfold2/2_5.jpg']`
```

Answer (score 1):

You code works correctly in Linux.
However you may want to simplify it by using [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk). Please see below:

```
new_names = []
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('dataset'):
    for filename in filenames:
        new_names.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

print(new_names)
```

which gives me following output:

```
['dataset/subfold2/93.jpg', 'dataset/subfold2/99.jpg', 'dataset/subfold2/97.jpg', 'dataset/subfold1/3.jpg', 'dataset/subfold1/2.jpg', 'dataset/subfold1/1.jpg']
```

Comment: ok . What is the difference between 'dataset/subfold2/93.jpg'  and 'dataset\\subfold2\\2_5.jpg'?   '/' and '//'

Comment: Are you in Windows?

Comment: I have windows 10

Comment: Then what you are seeing is Python escaping (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) your windows path separator `\` by a python escape char to put `\\`. it would work fine. That is just a visual thing you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're in `windows` OS. As you know in Windows `\` is the address separator.
And as `\` is the escape character in Python (it will be followed by another character indicating a special character, for example, `\t` means `tab`), thus the `\\` means `\`, and your addresses are totally correct and you can change the `/` to `\\` in compliance with the Windows rule. BTW, I strongly suggest you to apply the `pathlib` library. It is more convenient and powerful.

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path('MyPictures')
for image in p.iterdir():
    print(image)
```